# How to validate only onblur with Vuelidate?

Tags: vue.js, blur, vuelidate

From my parent component I'm calling my custom input child component this way:

```
<custom-input
  v-model="$v.form.userName.$model"
  :v="$v.form.userName"
  type="text"
/>
```

And here's my custom input component:

```
<template>
  <input
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :value="value"
    v-on="inputListeners"
    :class="{ error: v && v.$error }"
  >
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    v: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    inputListeners () {
      const vm = this
      return Object.assign({},
        this.$listeners,
        {
          input (event) {
            vm.$emit('blur', event.target.value)
          }
        }
      )
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This triggers validation errors from the very first character entered in the input field (which is arguably poor UX, so I really don't understand why this is default behavior).

Anyway, how to trigger such errors only on `blur` event?

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: Uh I'm referring to normal validation errors, I want validation to occur on blur event not input event

Comment: instead of `v-on="inputListeners"` try out `@blur="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to emit the input event from the handler of `blur` event so :

instead of :

```
v-on="inputListeners"
```

set

```
@blur="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not default behavior - it's your code!

Vuelidate validates (and raise errors) only after field is marked as dirty by calling [`$touch` method](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-v-methods). But when you are using `$model` property (`$v.form.userName.$model`) for `v-model`, it calls `$touch` automatically - [docs](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-v-values)

So either do not use `$model` for binding and call `$touch` by yourself on `blur` event (or whenever you want)

Alternatively you can try to use `.lazy` [modifier on v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy) but that is supported only on native input elements (support for custom components is [long time request](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6914))

Example below shows how to implement it yourself....

```js
Vue.use(window.vuelidate.default)

Vue.component('custom-input', {
  template: `
  <input
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :value="value"
    v-on="inputListeners"
    :class="status(v)"
  ></input>
  `,
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    v: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    },
    lazy: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    inputListeners() {
      const listeners = { ...this.$listeners }
      const vm = this
      const eventName = this.lazy ? 'change' : 'input'
      
      delete listeners.input
      listeners[eventName] = function(event) {
        vm.$emit('input', event.target.value)
      }
            
      return listeners
    }
  },
  methods: {
    status(validation) {
      return {
        error: validation.$error,
        dirty: validation.$dirty
      }
    }
  }
})

const { required, minLength } = window.validators

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    userName: ''
  },
  validations: {
    userName: {
      required,
      minLength: minLength(5)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.dirty {
  border-color: #5A5;
  background: #EFE;
}

.dirty:focus {
  outline-color: #8E8;
}

.error {
  border-color: red;
  background: #FDD;
}

.error:focus {
  outline-color: #F99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate/dist/vuelidate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate/dist/validators.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <custom-input v-model="$v.userName.$model" :v="$v.userName" type="text" lazy></custom-input>
  <pre>Model: {{ userName }}</pre>
  <pre>{{ $v }}</pre>
</div>
```